# How to use same functionalities of function present in one component to another based on click to use same class binding in both components in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using class binding to add and remove classes based on click of sidebar button to minimize and maximize the sidebar.
I need same functionality to add and remove class in footer component also to maximize and minimize width of the footer based on click made in sidebar component.

sidebar.component.html

```
<nav class="sidebar-container" [ngClass]="minimize ? 'minimize' : ''">
    <ul>
        <li class="sidebar-minimize">
            <a (click)="clickEvent()">Minmax</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

sidebar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  minimize: boolean = false;
ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  clickEvent() {
    this.minimize = !this.minimize;
  }
}
```

But i need same actions to be performed in footer component to add another CSS class through class binding followed by same clickEvent() method because in my situation sidebar component and footer components are interdependent on this clickEvent() function

For eg,

```
<footer (click)="clickEvent()" [ngClass]="minimize ? 'minimize':''">
<p>footer works</p>
</footer>
```

Is it possible to use same clickEvent() function in footer component for class binding

Comment: A good way to achieve this is with a service that both components get, which has some signal that let's them know to show/hide. Check out https://itnext.io/simple-sliding-side-bar-for-your-angular-web-apps-d54fef7c1654

Comment: Have you ran your code? It certainly works.

Comment: He's trying to make the sidebar toggle the footer, as far as I understand, which isn't working @Misha

Comment: Seems that it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-angular6-ozc9pj

Comment: @MishaMashina As per your blitz you used footer code in app component only. But in my case footer is a separate component and sidebar is separate component. But i need same  actions in both the component at a  time

Comment: Then you can go with the service, as @Donald suggested, or use `@Output` to emit from child-components to parent function that handles changing the 'minimize' var, and `@Input` to receive 'minimize' from parent.

Answer (score 1):

So in this case you can use a service. For example in your service you have a property like below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

 private minimize: boolean;
 public minimizeSubject: Subject<void>;

 constructor() {
  this.minimizeSubject = new Subject<void>();
  this.minimize = false;
 }

set setMinimize(minimize: boolean) {
 this.minimize = minimize;
 this.minimizeSubject.next();
}
```

Sidebar component should look like below:

```
export class SidebarComponent{

 public minimize: boolean;

 constructor(private testService: TestService) {
   this.minimize = false;
 }

 public onClicked(): void {
   this.minimize = !this.minimize;
   this.testService.setMinimize = this.minimize;
 }
```

In the end the footer component:

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private testService: TestService) {

    this.subscription = new Subscription();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.testService.minimizeSubject.subscribe(minimize => {
        this.minimize = minimize;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```